# For a black hole of a given mass, how long would it last?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, estimation, hawking-radiation, black-hole-thermodynamics

Given a black hole with mass $M$, assuming no mass is added, how long would it take for Hawking radiation to completely evaporate it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient prior research. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#A_crude_analytic_estimate

Comment: @RobJeffries no one cares

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but Jerry Schirmer's calculation is incorrect. Firstly, although the Planck-units temperature is indeed $1/(8\pi M)$, for dimensional consistency it should be $M_{Pl}^2 c^2/(8\pi kM)=c^3/(8\pi kG\hbar M)$. Note this introduces a $G$-dependence, which makes a lot of sense. I'll do the calculation properly without Planck units until the end; it's easy to avoid mistakes that way. Secondly, $-\dot{M}c^2$ isn't $\sigma T^4$; it's $\sigma AT^4$. So:

$$R=2M,\,A=4\pi R^2=16\pi M^2,\,\sigma=\frac{\pi^2}{60},\dot{M}=-\frac{\pi^2}{60}\frac{16\pi M^2}{(8\pi M)^4}=-\frac{1}{15360\pi M^2}.$$Hence $$\dot{M^3}=-\frac{1}{5120\pi}M_{Pl}^3t_{Pl}^{-1}=-\frac{1}{5120\pi}\frac{c^4\hbar}{G^2}.$$Equivalently, for an initial mass of $M_0$ that isn't fed later, the lifetime is $\dfrac{5120\pi G^2 M_0^3}{c^4 \hbar}$.

Comment: You are, of course, correct.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Can you, please, give some concrete numbers in years for a reference mass like the sun?

Comment: @freecharly A black hole of 1 Solar mass would have a lifetime of approximately $2.098\times 10^{67}$ Earth years. The lowest mass of astronomical black holes is a thorny issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_black_hole But among empirical examples it's $3.8$ solar masses.

Comment: @J.G. - Thank you, this is, indeed, an enormous number. Thank you also for the link. Very interesting!